# how to combine two linq query result set into one using C#

Tags: c#

I want to combine two LINQ query results into one:

```
var query1 = from sn in code                                        
             group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g
             select new
             {
               Key = g.Key,
               Cnt = g.Count(),
               Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10, 4)),
               Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10, 4))
             };
var query2 = from sn1 in codes
             group sn1 by sn1.Substring(0, 11) into g
             select new
             {
               key = g.Key,
               Cnt = g.Count(),
               Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(11, 4)),
               max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(11, 4))
             };
var query3= query1.Union(query2)
```

but on compilation I get an error:

> '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`' does not
>   contain a definition for '`Union`' and the best extension method
>   overload
>   '`System.Linq.Queryable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)`' has some invalid
>   arguments

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: could you please show query1 and query2 ?

Comment: There certainly is `Enumerable.Union` that combined two `IEnumerable<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx Therefore I expect you might either have `typeof(query1)` is not the same as `typeof(query2)`, or you are not using `System.Linq`.

Comment: @Raphael Althaus, i have edited my question above

Comment: hi @Tim Schmelter, i tried but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first query you select to an anonymous type with the properties "Key, Cnt, Min, Max", in the second you use the properties "key, Cnt, Min, max". This will result in two different anonymous types, because "Key" is not equal to "key" and "max" is not equal to "Max". And you can't use union with two different types.

Change your second query to this:

```
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Key = g.Key,
                                      Cnt = g.Count(),
                                      Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(11, 4)),
                                      Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(11, 4))
                                  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The code as given is not where the problem is. Example:

```
var query1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(n => new {SomePropName = n});
var query2 = Enumerable.Range(2, 3).Select(n => new {SomePropName = n});
var query3 = query1.Union(query2);
```

The above works, and fits the pattern you show in your code.

So the problem is in one of the bits you aren't showing. Key suspect would be that the element types of `query1` and `query2` don't match.

Do the anonymous objects of both, have the same field types, with the same names, in the same order? Their not having that would be the first thing I'd look for.

Edit:

Yes, in your edited question where the type in query1 has a field called `Max` that in query2 has one called `max`, and `Key` where query2 has `key`. That makes them different types, so they can't be unioned.

This will work:

```
var query1=from sn in code                                        
                                group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Key = g.Key,
                                    Cnt = g.Count(),
                                    Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10, 4)),
                                    Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10, 4))
                                };
var query2=from sn1 in codes
                                  group sn1 by sn1.Substring(0, 11) into g
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Key = g.Key,
                                      Cnt = g.Count(),
                                      Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(11, 4)),
                                      Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(11, 4))
                                  };
var query3= query1.Union(query2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using an anonymous type: `new{}` use a type that you defined

```
public class MyType 
{
   public int Key { get; set; }
   public int Cnt { get; set; }
   public int Min { get; set; }
   public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

then you replace the 2 selects with : `select new MyType { key = g.key }`

If you want to combine them:
query1.Union(query2);

If you want to add the results, you can do `AddRange`:

```
query1.ToList().AddRange(query2);
```

Comment: -1: That has rather different semantics: 1. it doesn't remove duplicate elements, 2. it forces evaluation of both queries.

Comment: And additionally, it probably won't work, since it doesn't address the underlying problem that the OP is describing - namely, that either `query1` and `query2` are different types, so the `AddRange` will fail, or that System.Linq isn't used, so that `ToList` will fail. It's different syntax that will hit the same problem.s

Comment: It still uses `ToList()` for no reason other than to waste time and memory, which is a premature pessimisation, and doesn't remove duplicates like `Union` does.

Comment: `ToList().AddRange(...)` is still a poor approach even without duplicate elimination: [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) would be better. Plus, post Q edit the accepted answer indicates the problem: two different anonymous types.